# Print cubes of the numbers 1 through 10 only if the cube is evenly divisible by four

Tags: python, list

Is everything right with code_cademy here ?

[image]

```
cubes_by_four = [x*x*x for x in range(1,10) if (x*x*x) % 4 == 0]

for x in cubes_by_four:
    print x
```

They are asking me to print each cube which is evenly divisible by four for numbers between 1 to 10. What am I doing wrong here ?

Also is this notation `x^3` allowed to get the cube of x ? if yes then why does is it results in wrong output ?

[image]

Comment: As a sidenote: You can use `x**3`
 to get the cube

Comment: Yup, use x**3 for cubes

Comment: Did you try printing the list directly, instead of just the elements in a loop? Like: `print cubes_by_four`

Comment: @Keiwan okay thanks got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Finally **print that list** to the console

```
>>> cubes_by_four = [x**3 for x in range(1,11) if x**3 % 4 == 0]
>>> print(cubes_by_four)
[8, 64, 216, 512, 1000]
```

It says print the list, not print each item in the list to console

Answer (score 1):

When you write `range(1,10)`, you include 1 but exclude 10.

So correct code is:

```
cubes_by_four = [x*x*x for x in range(1,11) if (x*x*x) % 4 == 0]

print cubes_by_four:
```

It will be a good practice to use x**3 for cubes.

`cubes_by_four = [x**3 for x in range(1,11) if (x**3) % 4 == 0]`

Comment: Please see screenshot in question.

Comment: Try using x**3 for cubes, maybe they want you to use this method.

Comment: You should print that list to console as `print cubes_by_four`

Answer (score 0):

Your range is off. You need `range(1, 11)`, because the second argument of `range()` is the *first value to exclude*. `range(1, 10)` only gives you number 1 through 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the value `10` you must change the range to `range(1, 11)`, since the range does *not* include the second parameter.

In regular Python, `x^3` does not mean exponentiation but rather the binary operation "bitwise exclusive or". That is exponentiation in SageMath (which is based on Python) but not in regular Python, which uses `x**3`, or as in your code, `x*x*x`.

Since you want to print out the list all in one line, including the surrounding brackets, just print using `print x`. Use that instead of your last two lines of code.

Comment: Please see screenshot in question.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `range` is not included in the range.

Is it between 1 and 10? or is it 1 through 10?

between 1 and 10 is `range(2,10)`

1 through 10 is `range(1,11)`

Answer (score 0):

Okay , a couple of things to keep in mind :-
1) if you want numbers 1-10 , do `range(1,11)` , since the last number is excluded, while the first number is (obviously) , included.
2) instead of `(x*x*x)` , you can something better like :- `pow(x,3)` , which essentially means x to the power 3,or x cubed.

So,your final code becomes :-
`cubes = [pow(x,3) for x in range(1,11) if pow(x,3) % 4 == 0]`

I hope this helps you , keep learning , getting stuck is a part of the wonderful journey in the world of programming . Cheers ! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate problems with the code you showed here:

First, change `range(1,10)` to `range(1,11)` because Python doesn't include the second parameter (10), and 10^3 is evenly divided by 4 (1000/4 = 250).

And finally, the tutorial wants you to print the numbers all in a single line, so just use `print cubes_by_four` instead of the `for` loop that you used to print each number in a different line.

Answer (score 0):

> script that prints the first 10 cube numbers (x**3), starting with x=1 and ending with x=10

```
for x in range(1,11):
 print(x*x*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that helped me, was realizing that the range **excludes** 1, i.e.: `range(0,9)` will only do 0-8, the right way to do it unless you want 0-8 is 0-10.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-python/lessons/advanced-topics-in-python/exercises/now-you-try):

> Use a list comprehension to create a list, cubes_by_four.
>
> The comprehension should consist of the cubes of the numbers 1 through
> 10 only if the cube is evenly divisible by four.
>
> Finally, print that list to the console.
>
> Note that in this case, the cubed number should be evenly divisible by
> 4, not the original number.

```
cubes_by_four = [x ** 3 for x in range(1,11) if (x ** 3) % 4 == 0]
print cubes_by_four
```

Result:[8, 64, 216, 512, 1000] ie: Range of 5 cubed numbers (evenly divisible by 4)

Answer (score -1):

```
for x in range(1,11):
    print(x*x*x)
```